# Error using stream dashboard: CSRF Failed

Tags: getstream-io

Whenever I try to do any actions on the getStream dashboard, I get an error message saying CSRF failed.  I can't create and app, or edit/add a feed group.  Every thing fails.  I attempted making a new account, logging out/in.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried deleting any cookies and logging in again?

Comment: That seems to have worked, kind of feeling silly for not thinking of that myself.  Thanks!